# complex ORDER BY with clauses

Tags: mysql, case, sql-order-by

I'm having problems trying to order the results from a MySQL query.

The table contains user information, notably:

- user_status (an integer)
- user_verified (boolean)
- last_login (date)

The ORDER BY clause should group users into 6 main groups and within each group order them by the last_login DESC.

Thus I'm trying to get (in pseudo code):

```
first show users: user_status = 1 AND user_verified = true, last_login DESC
then: user_status = 1 AND user_verified = false, last_login DESC
then: user_status = 2 AND user_verified = true, last_login DESC
then: user_status = 2 AND user_verified = false, last_login DESC
then: user_status = 0 AND user_verified = true, last_login DESC
then: user_status = 0 AND user_verified = false, last_login DESC
```

I'm having problems putting this together into a coherent ORDER BY clause so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use boolean expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause, because they are evaluated as `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`.

In your case you can simplify your requirement to:

```
ORDER BY user_status = 1 DESC,
         user_status = 2 DESC,
         user_status = 0 DESC,
         user_verified DESC,
         last_login DESC;
```

or:

```
ORDER BY CASE user_status 
           WHEN 1 THEN 1
           WHEN 2 THEN 2
           WHEN 0 THEN 3
         END,
         user_verified DESC,
         last_login DESC;
```

or with [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(user_status, 1, 2, 0),
         user_verified DESC,
         last_login DESC;
```

Comment: It certainly works, thank you! The logic threw me a bit... so it's order by the first field and then only if there are duplicates in that first field does field 2 kick in. Right... I think I have it! Thank you!

Comment: @arathra check also FIELD() function in my edited answer. It's simpler but since it is a function no index will be used.